# Why doesn't this example of recursion work?

Tags: php, recursion

I'm writing a function for exploring an XML document, and need to use recursion. It's not *quite* behaving how I wanted, so started running some tests.

```
<?php

$i=0;
function recursion(){
    $i++;
    if($i < 10){recursion();}
    echo $i;
    }
recursion();
?>
```

This generates a 500 Internal Server Error. Seems like I'm mishandling something - can someone help me out?

Comment: you need to add `global $i;` to the top of the function. That will allow for $i to retain it's value.. however I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: add this to first line of function: `global $i;`

Comment: @Farnabaz: That will make the code run but it's the worst possible solution because it encourages global variables.

Comment: Even when you do get the recursion fixed using the answers below, I'm not sure the output will be as you expect: http://codepad.org/iBbUTny5. Once `$i` reaches 10, it echoes the number once for each recursive call. Not sure you really need recursion, unless that's what you actually want it to do.

Comment: @Jon response works just fine, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12459728/227411

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$i` inside the function does not refer to the global variable `$i`, so it is always 1 and the script overflows the stack.

You could make `$i` global, but it's much better to pass it as an argument:

```
function recursion($i){
    $i++;
    if($i < 10){recursion($i);}
    echo $i;
}

recursion(0);
```

Comment: or make it private `private $_i = 0` to the class and use $this to access it (`$this-_i`)

Comment: @sweettea: I don't see a class here.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

 function recursion($i = 0){
   $i++;
   if($i < 10){recursion($i);}
   echo $i;
  }
recursion();
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the argument

```
$i=0;
function recursion($i){
    $i++;
    if($i < 10){recursion($i);}
    echo $i;
    }
recursion($i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `i` as a parameter to the function after incrementing, otherwise it wouldnt be recognized

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing $i inside your function as a local variable. If you want to reference de the global variable use the reserved word global:

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    function recursion(){
        global $i;
        $i++;
        if($i < 10){recursion();}
        echo $i;
    }
recursion();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will work fine, but nobody mentioned this option, so I'll just throw it out there.

You could also use the `static` keyword:

```
function recursion(){
    static $i = 0;
    $i++;
    if($i < 10){recursion();}
    echo $i;
}

recursion();
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope of $i is local in your example, $i is getting initialized on every call and become indefinite loop.
PHP abort the script by producing the fatal error after reaching 200 call

*Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting!*

Please try,

```
$i = 0;
function recursion() {
    global $i;
    $i++;
    echo $i;
    if ($i < 10) {
        recursion();
    }
}

recursion();
```